# List down all rows based on Date From & Date To Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Been trying to solve this problem.

I have this sample data to get the rows who are in between Date From and Date to:

Sheet1

This sheet contains Date From: and Date To: cells that will automatically shows the result below

[image]

Here's my Sheet2 where the data extracted from

[image]

Here's my current VBA code.

```
   Sub FinalData()

        Dim lastrow As Long
        Dim count As Integer
        Dim p As Integer
        Dim x As Integer

        lastrow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
         Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5:C1000").ClearContents

          count = 0
          p = 5
          For x = 2 To lastrow

          If Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2:C100") >= Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2) AND Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2:C100") <= Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2) Then

          Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(p, 1) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 1)

          Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(p, 2) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 2)

          Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(p, 3) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 3)

          p = p + 1
          count = count + 1

          End If

          Next x

          MsgBox " The number of data found for this Area is " & " " & count
    End Sub
```

Is there something wrong with my code? This code works fine from my last project but when I try to use this to get the rows for Date. I think the problem is on the conditional statement that I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to compare a range of cells with two single cells.

Untested:

```
   Sub FinalData()

        Dim lastrow As Long
        Dim count As Long
        Dim p As Long
        Dim x As Long, dt
        Dim wsReport As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet

        Set wsReport = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

        lastrow = wsData.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        wsReport.Range("A5:C1000").ClearContents

        count = 0
        p = 5

        For x = 2 To lastrow
            dt = wsData.Cells(x, "C")
            If dt >= wsReport.Cells(1, 2) And dt <= wsReport.Cells(2, 2) Then
                With wsReport
                    .Cells(p, 1) = wsData.Cells(x, 1)
                    .Cells(p, 2) = wsData.Cells(x, 2)
                    .Cells(p, 3) = wsData.Cells(x, 3)
                End With

                p = p + 1
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next x

        MsgBox " The number of data found for this Area is " & " " & count
    End Sub
```